# Why is crontab not running a python script

Tags: python, cron

This is how I configure crontab (by using `crontab -e`)

`* * * * * /home/jeff/Desktop/scripts/job_pull_queue.sh >> /home/jeff/Desktop/scripts/log.txt`

This is the content of `/home/jeff/Desktop/scripts/job_pull_queue.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Running job_pull_queue.sh @ $(date)"
cd /home/jeff/Documents/code/some_project
echo $(printenv)
/home/jeff/miniconda3/bin/python -m util.main
```

Now the problem is, when running `./job_pull_queue.sh` in the terminal, it works, but I can tell from the log file that `crontab` never executes that last line `/home/jeff/miniconda3/bin/python -m util.main` (I can see the result from the previous `echo` in the log file, but not the python script itself), what happened? How do I fix it?

Update: here's the result from `printenv` when ran by crontab

```
SHELL=/bin/sh PWD=/home/jeff/Documents/code/some_project LOGNAME=jeff HOME=/home/jeff LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SHLVL=0 PATH=/usr/bin:/bin OLDPWD=/home/jeff _=/usr/bin/printenv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok...

My Python script reads several env variables from my user profile, and of course, these variables don't exist when `crontab` is running the script...

And I don't have detection/logging in place so I didn't know env variables are missing.